# cannot convert values into string to string[] how to pass values?

Tags: asp.net

I need to pass values into `.dbml`

> how could i pass values to string[] parameter ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
[FileUpload(FileTypes = new string[] {"filetype1", "filetype2", ...})]
```

Note that this has nothing to do with the .dbml file, or LINQ2SQL in general. This is basic named parameters for attributes.